# Fire jquery event when a new dropdown value gets set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 options in the dropdown.

```
<select id="_fid_140" onchange="chooseRecordPicker()" >
<option value="736">9000000146</option>
<option value="x3recpcker#">&lt; Browse choices... &gt;</option>
```

After clicking on Browse choices, a new window opens, I make a selection there, I hit save. The options in the dropdown change to

```
 <option value="740">9000000140</option>
 <option value="x3recpcker#">&lt; Browse choices... &gt;</option>
```

I want an event to be fired after "a new value has been set" in the dropdown.

Comment: the onchange event opens the new window. 
<select id="_fid_140" onchange="chooseRecordPicker()" >

I want an event which will be fired only after the value has been set.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').change(function(){
    //Run your function here. 
});
```

This function will run when the dropdown menu selected option has been changed.

Comment: I think what is need is something like option_value_change event and not option_change event. Any suggestions on how I can fire an event when value of an option changes.

Comment: The change event only occurs when a change is completed on the options and each option should have a unique value. http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/jXA3Q/ Daniel's answer is correct @PriyankaA. Now, if you're changing a single option's value from one thing to another, then that is a horse of a different color.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for changing the "value" of an option. I want to fire an event when that happens.